# CSS, grouping elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to group elements by `( )`, but I am close to belive that this is impossible. Is it?
Do I really have to do this like this:

```
#column-group-beta div.moduletable.title4 li a,
#column-group-beta div.moduletable.title4 li a:link, 
#column-group-beta div.moduletable.title4 li a:visited, 
#column-group-beta div.moduletable.title4 li a:focus, 
#column-group-beta div.moduletable.title4 li a:active, 
div.title4 li a,
div.title4 li a:link, 
div.title4 li a:visited, 
div.title4 li a:focus, 
div.title4 li a:active {

}
```

instead of

```
#column-group-beta div.moduletable.title4 li (a,a:link,a:visited, a:focus,a:active) 
div.title4 li (a,a:link,a:visited, a:focus,a:active) {

}
```

Comment: Why do you need the ID selector if you already have `div.title4`? That looks like a specificity issue that you should try and sort out first.

Comment: it doesn't matter, it still require to be repeated 5 times even for clear `li a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you really have to do it the correct way that the CSS formatting requires.

That said, when your CSS gets this specific:

```
#column-group-beta div.moduletable.title4 li a:link
```

It's likely already a mess. This happens. A lot. And is sometimes necessary, but if you have the luxury, maybe rethink the CSS altogether.